# Does there exist some $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, deg$(p) > 1$, which maps $\mathbb{Q}$ onto itself surjectively?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials

Clearly this is impossible for $p$ of even degree, and I imagine that Cardano’s formula quickly reveals it to be impossible in the cubic case, although I have not checked in detail. My guess is that no such $p$ exists. Does one exist? If so, is there an explicit example?

Failing a general yes or no answer, are there sufficient conditions to identify a non-surjective polynomial function?

Comment: Nope cause you won’t hit $1/p$ for $p$ large (lemme know if I’m being stupid!).

Comment: Perhaps $\ \mathbb Q\setminus f(\mathbb Q)\ $ is dense in $\ \mathbb Q$.

Comment: (…because wlog by scaling $f\in \Z[x]$, and then when $p$ doesn’t divide the leading coefficient $c_0$ of $f(x) =: c_0 x^d + \cdots + c_d\in \Z[x]$ the $p$-adic valuation of ($(a,b) = 1$) $f(a/b) = b^{-d} (c_0 a^d + c_1 a^{d-1} b + \cdots + c_d b^d) = b^{-d} (c_0 a^d + (\in b\Z))$ is either $\geq 0$ (when $(p,b)=1$) or a multiple of $d$ (when $p\vert b$, whence $(p,a) = 1$), so it can’t be $-1$.)

Comment: Stronger question answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186768/images-of-polynomials

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, this can't happen. One way to prove this is via Hilbert irreducibility: The polynomial $p(x) - t$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x,t]$, so there are infinitely many specializations $t = c$ with $c \in \mathbb Q$ such that $p(x) - c$ is irreducible in  $\mathbb Q[x]$. Since the degree of $p(x)$ is greater than 1, it follows that for each such $c$ the polynomial $p(x) - c$ has no rational roots.

Comment: Fascinating. This is the first I’ve heard about the Hilbert irreducibility theorem. I will read more about it. Thank you!

Comment: This shows that a similar statement holds when we replace the field of rational numbers by a Hilbertian field (e.g., a number field or finitely generated field of characteristic zero).

Answer (score 17):

John's answer is good, but an alternative, more elementary, method is to use the theory of height functions. Thus for a fraction in lowest terms $a/b$, we define the height of $a/b$ to be
$$ H(a/b) = \max\bigl\{ |a|,|b|\bigr\}. $$
One can show that if $p(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, then there is a constant $C_1(p)>0$ depending only on $p$ such that
$$ H\bigl(p(a/b)\bigr) \ge C_1(p) H(a/b)^d. $$
From this one can prove a counting result:
$$ \# \bigl\{ a/b\in\mathbb Q : H\bigl(p(a/b)\bigr) < X \bigr\} \le C_2(p)\cdot X^{2/d}. $$
On the other hand, it's not hard to see that here is a constant $C_3>0$ such that
$$ \#\bigl\{ a/b\in\mathbb Q: H(a/b) < X\bigr\} \ge C_3\cdot X^2. $$
So the heights of the values of $p(a/b)$ grow too rapidly to cover all of $\mathbb Q$. (Indeed, part of the proof of Hilbert irreducibility uses an argument of this sort.)

Comment: Should $f$ be $p$?

Comment: Note that Joe's answer also makes it clearer that something stronger is true: Not only is the set of points in $\mathbb Q \setminus p(\mathbb Q)$ infinite, but the image $p(\mathbb Q)$ is actually quite sparse in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @MattF. Yes, thanks, I'll fix that. I'm really used to the letter $p$ being a prime!

Comment: @JohnDoyle True, although a more refined version of Hilbert irreducibility is that the exceptional set is a *thin* set, so has exactly this sparsity property relative to the usual height function. So your answer already implicitly includes the sparisty of $\mathbb Q\smallsetminus p(\mathbb Q)$.

Answer (score 8):

I claim that no polynomial $q$ of degree greater than $1$ and rational coefficients can be a surjective mapping from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose that a polynomial $q$ of degree greater than $1$ is surjective from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. For simplicity, by replacing $q(x)$ with $p(x)=\alpha(q(\beta x)-\gamma)$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are rational with $\alpha,\beta\neq 0$, we can assume that $p(x)$ is a surjective monic polynomial with constant term $0$ and integer coefficients. Suppose now that $p(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{1}x$ where the coefficients $a_{1},\dots,a_{n-1}$ are integers.

If $\alpha,\beta$ are integers with $p(x)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, then $\beta x^{n}+\dots+\beta a_{1}x=\alpha$, so by the rational root theorem, $x$ must be of the form $\frac{r}{s}$ where $r$ is a factor of $\alpha$ and $s$ is a factor of $\beta$. In particular, in the case where $\beta=1$, if $p(x)=\alpha$, then $x$ must be a factor of $\alpha$. Therefore,
$p$ must restrict to a surjective function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. This is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. This is the most elementary one yet.

Comment: I don't see how replacing $q$ by $\alpha (q(\beta x)-\gamma )$ produces a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Suppose that $q(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+\dots+a_{0}$. Let $q_{1}(x)=q(x)-a_{0}$. Then $q_{1}(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+\dots+a_{1}x$. Let $q_{2}(x)=q_{1}(a)/a_{n}$. Then $q_{2}(x)=x^{n}+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+b_{1}x$. Now select a non-zero integer $b$ such that $b^{n-k}b_{k}$ is an integer for $1\leq k<n$. Then let $p(x)=x^{n}+b\cdot b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+b^{n-1}\cdot b_{1}x$. Then $p(x)=b^{n}q_{2}(x/b)$.

Comment: Oh, sure! Thank you.